# Filter an array by value with another array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

Here an example element of the first array "filteredPrestations" :

```
​​[
  2: {
   name: 'Test',
   service: {
     _id:'12345678910'
   }
  }
]
```

Here my array "serviceIds" of Ids :

```
[
  1: "12345678910"
  2: "10987654321"
  3: "13579246790"
]
```

I want to filter the first array with only elements that they have an service id in the list of the second array.

I tried this :

```
this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => item.service._id.includes(this.servicesIds));
```

Thank's !

Comment: The syntax of your `serviceIds` is invalid, it will throw an error on declaration

Comment: ^^ as the first array ...

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think he's trying to transcribe what it looks like in the console, not the source code syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.includes()` call is backwards. It should be

```
this.serviceIds.includes(item.service._id)
```

The general format is `array.includes(element)`